# Getting pk_set value in django signal runs into an atomic error

Tags: python, django

This is my signal

```
def my_signal(instance, action, pk_set, **kwrags):
    instance.animal_count = instance.animals.all().count()
    instance.save()
    if action == 'post_add':
        print pk_set #works
        print pk_set[0] #no work
```

The weird thing is, if I just print pk_set I get `set([1])` but if I try and get the actual value using [0] I run into:

```
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

Is there any way to just get the pk_set number? I literally only need the id.

Note: This happens during test cases.

Oddly enough if I do

```
list(pk_set)[0]
```

this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons doing

```
list(pk_set)[0]
```

works but this doesn't:

```
pk_set[0]
```